# Please show how to save bitmap file to directory

Tags: c#, bitmap

This code is about changing contrast parameter for jpg files via bitmap. I'm stuck in the point where I'm saving the result. I'm taking a photo (string s = ld[0];), then changing it and then trying to save as new (resultBitmap.Save(project.Directory + "_new.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);)
Please tell me what am I doing wrong! It doesn't save a new file to directory.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int threshold = rnd.Next(16,28);
string d = project.Directory + @"\avito\photos\";   
string[] ld = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
string s = ld[0];


Bitmap sourceBitmap = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(s)); //
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData sourceData = sourceBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                                sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height), 
                                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); 

byte[] pixelBuffer = new byte  [sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height]; 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, pixelBuffer, 0, pixelBuffer.Length); 
sourceBitmap.UnlockBits(sourceData); 

double contrastLevel = Math.Pow((100.0 + threshold) / 100.0, 2); 
double blue = 0; 
double green = 0; 
double red = 0; 
for (int k = 0; k + 4 < pixelBuffer.Length; k += 4) {
    blue = ((((pixelBuffer[k] / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrastLevel) + 0.5) * 255.0; 
    green = ((((pixelBuffer[k + 1] / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrastLevel) + 0.5) * 255.0; 
    red = ((((pixelBuffer[k + 2] / 255.0) - 0.5) *  
                    contrastLevel) + 0.5) * 255.0;   
        if  (blue > 255) 
        { blue = 255; } 
        else if  (blue < 0) 
        { blue = 0; } 

        if (green > 255) 
        { green = 255; } 
        else if (green < 0) 
        { green = 0; } 
   
        if (red > 255) 
        { red = 255; } 
        else if (red < 0) 
        { red = 0; } 

        pixelBuffer[k] = (byte)blue; 
        pixelBuffer[k + 1] = (byte)green; 
        pixelBuffer[k + 2] = (byte)red; 
    } 
Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height); 
System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData resultData = resultBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                                resultBitmap.Width, resultBitmap.Height), 
                                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pixelBuffer, 0, resultData.Scan0, pixelBuffer.Length);
resultBitmap.UnlockBits(resultData); 
resultBitmap.Save(project.Directory + "_new.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
resultBitmap.Dispose();
sourceBitmap.Dispose();
```

Comment: When asking a question related to code, it's always necessary for you to add a tag for the programming language you're using. Please [edit] your question to add that thag.

Comment: `It doesn't save a new file to directory.`  What does the debugger say is the value of `project.Directory`?  Otherwise, step through the code line by line with the debugger to see what is happening when it's running.

Comment: it says that there is no variable to write completion code. Sorry, I'm doing it via zennoposter program, not Visual studio...

Comment: Right before the line Bitmap resultBitmap = new Bitmap(sourceBitmap.Width, sourceBitmap.Height); it returns to line No 22 (for (int k = 0; k + 4 < pixelBuffer.Length; k += 4) {) and repeats it, never performing the resultBitmap thing

Comment: `it says that there is no variable to write completion code`  I have no idea what that means.  If that's an exception you are getting, you should edit your post with that full message.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [mre] and consider updating your question; while you provided your code, it is not minimal and hardly reproducible. This may require you do some debugging to figure out what is "minimal", a step you should always take on your own before posting here.

Comment: It's obvious that the `for` loop thing will be repeated a few thousand times; that loops over literally every pixel on the image. Don't debug over that; put your breakpoint behind it.